# Grub Recovery at Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, qnx

So I'm not exactly sure what happened but when I went to start my computer today, it failed to boot and the only thing on the screen is a command line with "Grub recovery". I tried to repair what happened with Boot Repair Disk but all it was able to do was dump the report linked here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15171771/

Now, this isn't my computer, so I don't know what's installed on it, but I'm pretty sure it's some sort of linux distribution as well as a QNX 4 install. If anyone knows how to repair grub with QNX, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: http://www.guia-ubuntu.com/index.php/Recuperar_GRUB ,this url your answer
good lucky

Answer (score 0):

Did someone try to install another bootable distribution on sdb drive? Maybe this broke your bootloader(s).
It seems you have installed syslinux on sdb and grub 2 on sda which are both bootloaders.
You could try to insert a live CD from any linux distribution and chroot into sda/sdb. Maybe deleting both and reinstalling one of them will fix it. Help for this can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Boot_loaders).

Or maybe just set the bootflag of sdb to false with fdisk. ([Here at Point 6](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-fdisk/))

Comment: The partition on sdb is the recovery disk. I installed it on a USB drive. sda1 is a ubuntu install and sda3 is a qnx4 install but for some reason the filesystems got corrupted. I'm able to boot into qnx using super grub2, but every other tool I use can't identify either install.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way,step by step:

1. You boot Super GRUB2 Disk.
2. Press `e` to enter the shell from the GRUB editor.
3. Now, you must reinstall GRUB to your hard disk ( usb at /dev/sdb ).
   Remember,
   sdb is unmounted, sdb is not sdb1. So, you type in the prompt

   ```
   grub>`grub-install /dev/sdb`
   ```
4. That's all. It's time for you to try again.
5. By the way, you might think about where you have installed GRUB 2.00:

   - GPT disk
   - MBR (Master Boot Record)
   - EFI (Extensible Firmware Interface)
     For this question,you might look carefully at
     [Recover from a failed Linux boot](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-GRUB2-features/)
6. I wish you luck.